# Subset con objetos S4 y valor lógico en un raster

Tags: r

Se ocupar los subset dentro de un raster con objetos S4, pero ahora necesito que la condición sea un objeto S4 y a la vez un valor lógico (posición dia juliano de una lista). Hasta el momento no me resulta y da un error.

```
#Filtro 
setwd("D:/Temporal2")
mypath9<-"D:/SNOWL"
myras9<-list.files(path=mypath9,pattern = glob2rx("*.tif$"), ## nc es la extension de HDF
                    full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
name9<-substr(myras9,26,28)

for (i in 1:(name9)){
r<-raster(myras9[1])
rt<-(name9[1])
ra<-(name9[126])
rd<-(name9[302])
tn<-(rt<=ra) & (rt<rd) #(1>=126) & (1<302)
tl<-(rt<ra) & (rt>=rd)
r[(r==1)&(tn)]<-3
r[(r==1)&(tl)]<-2
writeRaster(r,paste0("MOYDTF2",name9[i], sep=""),datatype='INT1U',format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
}

"Error in (r == 1) & (tn) : 
  solo son posibles operaciones para variables de tipo numérico, compleja o lógico"
```

Answer (score 0):

El error básicamente te está diciendo que `r` no es numérico, complejo o lógico. Lo cual es razonable por que entiendo que al hacer esto:

```
r<-raster(myras9[1])
```

Estas inicializando `r`como un `Raster* object`. No puedo ayudarte mucho más por que no se exactamente que quieres lograr.